# Looking for a children’s musical, "Amazing Grace"

Tags: resource-request, music

The lyric contains the words "Where I’d Superman when you need a helping hand?"

Comment: Is this your song: [The Superman Song](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lvDh5v5s2II)? Or are you looking for a complete album? It contains the words: **”Where is Superman, when you need a helping hand?”** It is slightly different from your quoted words.

Comment: I also found the a 2012 musical [Amazing Grace: the musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing_Grace_(musical)) based on the life of John Newton (the author of the hymn "Amazing Grace"), but I don't think it has the Superman song, and maybe you're referring to a different musical.  If you think this is the musical, I can look for where you can obtain the complete lyrics of the songs listed in the *Wikipedia* article.

Comment: The Superman song is the correct song. I’m looking for the musical that used that song. I think it’s called: Amazing Grace. The lead character is: amazing Grace.